# ChromeDriver language is not being set to English

Tags: java, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to set the language of my chrome driver to English, but none of the options are working for me. I am using java-selenium and the driver version is 111. I have tried to set the language using below methods

```
ChromeOptions opt = new ChromeOptions();
opt.addArguments("−−lang=es");
WebDriver drv = new ChromeDriver(opt);
```

below is the other code that I tried

```
        WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
        ChromeOptions ops = new ChromeOptions();

        Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<>();
        prefs.put("intl.accept_languages", "en,en_US");
        ops.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);

        ops.addArguments("--remote-allow-origins=*");
        ChromeDriver chromeDriver= new ChromeDriver(ops);

        chromeDriver.get("https://demo.openmrs.org/openmrs/login.htm");
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        chromeDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@placeholder='Enter username']")).sendKeys("admin");
        chromeDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@placeholder='Enter your password']")).sendKeys("Admin123");
        chromeDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//font[text()='Inpatient Ward']")).click();
        chromeDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='Log in']")).click();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        String title = chromeDriver.getTitle();
        System.out.println(title);
        chromeDriver.findElement(By.xpath(" //font[contains(text(),'end session')]")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change below line, as I can see you are using `longer` dashes instead of `hyphen` i.e. `--`

***From***

```
opt.addArguments("−−lang=es");
```

***To***

```
opt.addArguments("--lang=es");
```

***OR***

you can use the below way as well.

```
chrome_options.add_argument("--lang=en-US")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are doing right , you should need to use correct code for language. I think you want english so juse use

> `"options.addArguments("--lang=en");"`

Code:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--lang=en");
ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Comment: it changes the language of chrome but not the webpage